# Joint exponential probability

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, density-function, exponential-distribution

[image]

This is from gate 2021 statistics paper. The answer in key is given as 143. I got answer as 4 .
I used the formula for joint distribution under the condition $x_1+x_2 < y$

Here is my work:

if we let x1 and x2 as the arrival times for the next two visitors  while y is the departure time for one of the 10 visitors.

$x_1 \sim  exp(1)$

$x_2 \sim exp(1)$

$y \sim  exp(1)$

$x_1+x_2 = X \sim  erlang(1)$

X < y,  X >0

If we perform a double integral with above conditions , it will give 1/4, so 1/p = 4

$p =\int _{ X=0 }^{ \infty }\int _{ y= X }^{ \infty }xe^{-X}.e^{-y}\, dx dy = 1/4$

Comment: How are you accounting for the fact that there are 10 people who could leave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I thought someone may find it useful to know that the accepted answer isn't correct. Indulge me while I demonstrate my approach.

First suppose there are $n\geq 1$ in attendance at the amusement park. The probability that someone arrives before anyone in the park leaves is $$\mathbb{P}\left(\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}>Y\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}$$ Here $X_1,...,X_n\sim \text{Exponential}(1)$ represent the times each of the *n* individuals spend at the amusement park and $Y\sim \text{Exponential}(1)$ is the time is takes for the *next* individual to arrive at the amusement park.

Since we're starting with $10$ individuals in the amusement park and the exponential distribution is memoryless, the probability that *exactly* two individuals leave before the next customer arrives is $$p=\frac{1}{11}\cdot \frac{1}{12}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{13}\right)=\frac{1}{143}$$ Hence $\frac{1}{p}=143$

Comment: thank you. You are right. This is the answer as per the answer key

Comment: No problem. I made the same exact mistake as @Jellyfish when I first solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the time of the next departure of the 10 people, then $X$ is the minimum of 10 Exponential(1) random variables and so is distributed: $X\sim \text{Exponential}(10)$.

Let $Y$ be the number of arrivals by the next departure, then $Y$ given the next departure time $X$ is distributed as $Y|X\sim \text{Poisson}(X)$.

We are interested in $\Pr(Y=2)$ which by the law of total probability can be found to be

$$\begin{split}\Pr(Y=2)&=\int_0^\infty \Pr(Y=2|x)f(x)dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} x^2}{2!}10e^{-10x}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty 5e^{-11x}x^2dx\end{split}$$

After doing integration by parts twice we get that $p=\Pr(Y=2)=\frac{10}{1331}$ so $\frac 1p=133.1$.

Here is an alternative solution that gives the same answer. Let $X$ be the arrival time of the next two people, $Y$ be the departure time of the next person out of the 10 (thanks to the memorylessness property), and $Z$ be the arrival time of the third person.

$$\begin{split}X&\sim\text{Gamma}(2,1)\\
Y&\sim\text{Exponential}(10)\\
Z&\sim \text{Exponential}(1)\end{split}$$

We are interested in $\Pr(Z>Y-X,X<Y)$, because we need two people to arrive before the 1st departure and the third person to arrive after it. This integral is

$$\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\int_{y-x}^\infty10xe^{-(x+10y+z)}dzdydx\\
=\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty 10xe^{-11y}dydx\\
=\int_0^\infty \frac{10xe^{-11x}}{11}dx\\
=\frac {10}{1331}$$

Conclusion: Answer key is wrong. This problem is also intractable without consulting the memorylessness property.

Comment: Answer key is given as 143. Do you think there is any thing that could be missing? Also could you explain why my method didn't work?

Comment: @Stacker I can see that your solution certainly applies in a different scenario where the $10$ visitors arrive together *nonrandomly, all at the same time* $t$, because in that case the next departure would clearly be at time $t+X$, with $X$ distributed as the minimum of $10$ iid $Exp(1)$ rv's. But how can the same solution also apply -- and I'm not claiming that it doesn't -- if the $10$ visitors are just those remaining from all who arrived at *random times prior to time* $t$, according to the Poisson process?

Comment: I'm thinking the exponential distribution has the memoryless property, so it doesn't matter when you start counting their departure time. If they stayed up to a certain point, the distribution of their departure time is Exp(1). I.e. $P(X>k+t|X>t)=P(X>k)$.

Comment: Your answer is hard to follow. It vaguely looks like you are attempting something on the right lines but it is seriously flawed. For instance, x1 and x2 are indeed the next two arrival times, but it doesn't say that x1+x2+x3 will be greater than when the first of the ten people leave. Also what is erlang(1)? Gamma/erlang should have 2 parameters. Also as pointed out in the comment y only accounts for one visitor departing, but there are 10 visitors, so we need minimum of 10 y's.

Comment: `$ \lambda^2 xe^{-\lambda x) $` is the sum of two exponential distribution with parameter lambda.  Even I didn't know but I got it from internet. I understood my mistake of not using minimum of 10 visitors. But answer is still 143 not 133.1

Comment: This answer unfortunately isn't correct, and I made a similar mistake with my initial attempt. You're not accounting for the possibility that one of the two individuals who arrive may leave before any one of the ten individuals who are already at the park leave.